# Pinterest tag firing multiple times on single page app

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I am using the pinterest tag code out of the box on a single page app, and it fires multiple times on navigation. Any suggestions on how to make if fire only once?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
!function(e){if(!window.pintrk){window.pintrk=function(){window.pintrk.queue.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))};var n=window.pintrk;n.queue=[],n.version="3.0";var t=document.createElement("script");t.async=!0,t.src=e;var r=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];r.parentNode.insertBefore(t,r)}}("https://s.pinimg.com/ct/core.js");

pintrk('load','<YOUR_TAG_ID>', {
  em: '<email_address>',
});
pintrk('page');
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it’s firing multiple times? How many times is multiple?

Comment: The tag helper says "We detected 1 tag that fired 5 events" (That's after navigating through 5 pages).

Comment: Is that not correct? `pintrk('page')` is the correct event for a page? Are you using a frontend JavaScript framework with a single page application?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. the pinterest code was being loaded by a tag to the external library to my code. Thanks for your answers